# Need help to execute SQL in text file with SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I want to load an Excel file (`.XLS`) into a table in my database. The database is on my own computer and I have the sa account in SQL server 08. The Excel file contains -

```
Id  Name
1   Dog
2   Cat
3   Fish
```

The file (`demo.txt`) with SQL code:

```
insert into [MyDb].[dbo].[relative] 
   select *  
   from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;
                   Database=C:\My Temp Files\Excel','select * from [sheet1$]');
```

The `SQLCMD` code:

```
sqlcmd -S MyPc\SQL2008 -i "C:\My Temp Files\SQL\demo.txt"
```

The error in `sqlcmd`:

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Server MyPc\SQL2008, Line 1
>   OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

A fix (which does not solve the problem) for the above error
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/03/sql-server-fix-error-ms-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries-because-the-provider-is-used-to-run-in-apartment-mode/

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

How do I fix this thing and make it work ?

---

**EDITS -**

---

I tried the stuff in the comments of the above link and got the error -

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Server MyPc\SQL2008, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" report
ed an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Server MyPc\SQL2008, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB
.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

**What i tried -**

Download and install the new 64 bit component from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en

To install the above component, there is no need to uninstall 32bit Office apps first. We can install 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable components using command prompt.

```
C:\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive
```

Open up SQL Server and run the following:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

This sets the parameters needed to access and run queries related to the components. Address ‘null

Now, if you are running OPENROWSET calls you need to abandon calls, made using the old JET parameters and use the new calls as follows:

(*Example, importing an EXCEL file directly into SQL):

**DONT DO THIS…**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;
Database=c:\PATH_TO_YOUR_EXEXCEL_FILE.xls',
'select * from [sheet1$]')
```

**USE THIS INSTEAD…**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;
Database=c:\PATH_TO_YOUR_EXEXCEL_FILE.xls','select * from [sheet1$]')
```

Now, how do i fix the error this new approach gave me ?

Comment: A lot of the comments on that site indicate it is because you are using 64 bit Excel to access a 32 bit driver (though normally you get a different error). Is your SQL Server installation 64 bit? I think `SELECT @@VERSION` will tell you.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - One more error. I'll google that try to fix it.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - This is an endless nightmare of errors and configurations. Why don't people just use `SSIS` or any other tool instead. I took this up as an exercise and its wasting my time. I'll resume working on this another day. My excel installation is messed up. Don't know if the windows update or the command to install access components did it.

Comment: I agree it's far more painful that it should be. You are to be commended for sticking with it! To troubleshoot you could try creating a linked server in SQL and see if that gives you a better error. Excel is a nasty format to import from anyway. People have a habit of moving columns and rows and putting in formulas etc, and Excel has a habit of applying incorrect formats and data types. The problem could also be that the SQL Server can't access the file, or the file is already open by something else, or it doesn't like the data format.